# Conditional Rendering in JSX not hiding the Element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

So i have this react component which contains a conditional rendering in some part. so far so good and this practice has been acting as expected all throughout my app. 
but surprisingly the element we're talking is not getting hidden as a result of change in condition.
let me provide you with a minimal representation of relevant code because the original component is too lengthy and cumbersome.

```
import React from 'react';
import AnotherComponent from '../components/AnotherComponent';

export class TheComponent extends Component {
  /* 
    1. props.data is coming from mapping component state to redux connect
    2. connect file and selectors are alright, because other parts of this component
       work as expected, and even same props.data is used elsewhere in the component
    3. a method wihtout input as in showAnotherComponent = () => false; will hide the 
       AnotherComponent element successfully. but even sth like 
       showAnotherComponent = (data) => false; will not work!!!
    4. props.data is properly injected to the render method, console.log(props.data)  in reder 
       method will display updated value.
    5. props.data is never null or undefined and so on ..
  */
  showAnotherComponent = data => data.flag === 'AAA';

  render() {
    console.log(this.props.data); // will show the updated props.data

    return (
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-md-10">
          <h1>Some heading</h1>
        </div>
        <div className="col-md-2">
          {/* the element in next line will always show up invariably, whatever the
          content of props.data. tried ternary, same result. */}
          {this.showAnotherComponent(this.props.data) && <AnotherComponent />}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default TheComponent;
```

Unfortunately creating a fully working sample is a bit hard, considering all the third party dependencies and the redux wiring.
 Nevertheless, if you have ever run into similar situation and got to the bottom of it, please share your experience with me.

note: Updated props.data is passed to the component normally. in the react dev tools it shows up and in redux dev tools history of state is quite healthy. the only problem here is that the conditional won't hide the element in a falsy state.

UPDATE. the reason for this weird rendering was a dynamic loop in the same component rendering this AnotherComponent regardless of the flag value. what made it hard to pin down was that it was rendering it in map and passing index of dynamic string content. anyhow, thank you all and sorry for the possible misleading question.

Comment: Hmmm, it's quite hard to give a good solution without a verifiable example. Can you try doing one on a repl? If this is the only relevant code, I don't see why it wouldn't work.

Comment: What is your `console.log` showing you ?

Comment: @Treycos it'll show the updated value for the props.data. and it's fine because i have it displayed elsewhere in the same component.

Comment: @ObedMarquezParlapiano yea, i would've but you know it's just too much effort since this is my main container component for many others parts and i'm afraid cutting out the seemingly irrelevant parts would defeat the purpose and even not reproduce the issue.

Comment: Do you have componentShouldUpdate anywhere in your component? This happened to me once because I had a cSU that didn't meet the case I was expecting. ---- edit: nevermind, you said the value updates somewhere else in your component.

Comment: @ObedMarquezParlapiano the only life-cycle method present in the component is ComponentWillReceiveProps, and it will only update state based on some other props. even removed it altogether and didn't change a thing.

Comment: You’re afraid that cutting out seemingly irrelevant parts would not reproduce the issue, but then you’re asking us to help without seeing those same seemingly irrelevant parts. Start a CodeSandbox with just the parts you think are relevant and then incrementally make it closer to your real code until you reproduce the issue.

Comment: *even sth like 
       showAnotherComponent = (data) => false; will not work* - that's very unlikely. It's impossible, a param doesn't affect anything here. There could be problems with hot reload if you use it in your app or some other condition that prevents the app from working normally. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that can replicate the problem. The thing you're describing just doesn't add up. There may be problems with how you reproduce the problem or interpret console output.

Comment: @RyanCogswell ok, i'll try to do that as well. i just assumed this might be some frequent issue in react and the hint is out there. i will try to create a running sample but it might take a day because this is company code and i don't have access to it right now.

Comment: @estus i agree this is just ridiculous, that's why i put 3 exclamation marks in there :) yea i'll try and come up with some working sample soon.

Comment: You aren't using Enzyme at all at this point. The way you test with react-test-renderer seems to be ok (you will have hard time testing everything with it though), so it's unclear what the problem could be.

Comment: what does the `console.lgo(this.showAnotherComponent(this.props.data))` shows? it seems that it always return true

Comment: @estus as a matter of fact i do use Enzyme+Jest for unit testing. this bug was reported very late today and i was gonna create a test case for it using mocked props tomorrow. so, i'll give you feedback when i get a clue on it :)

Comment: Good point. What does that console log that @Amir-Mousavi mentioned returns?

Comment: @Amir-Mousavi props.data is a string prop, in checker function i'll just check its value against some certain string. and no, it does not always return true. that is why i'm baffled here :)

Comment: @ObedMarquezParlapiano it returns different values, all boolean

Comment: If it doesn't always return true, and your component it's not hiding, you've got a rendering error. Something it's preventing your component from updating and hiding the element. Check your component with react dev tools, see if you find any hints there.

Comment: @ObedMarquezParlapiano of course there is some rendering issue, otherwise it doesn't make sense. ReactDevTools doesn't show anything wrong strange enough.

Comment: @SiavashRostami Sure, consider pinging me. That you have this in tests is totally different case. Apart from other considerations, Enzyme's behaviour differs from React renderer, the problem could be specific to the way tests are written.

Comment: @estus Yes indeed Enzyme test is the best place to isolate the behavior. will update here tomorrow :)

Comment: UPDATE. the reason for this weird rendering was a part in the same component rendering this AnotherComponent regardless of the flag value. what made it hard to pin down was that it was rendering it in map and passing index of dynamic string content. anyhow, thank you all and sorry for the silly puzzle.

Answer (score 0):

It is working fine here.

You should check the data in your props if there is any `flag` key or not and if there is a `flag` key check that if it is `AAA` or not.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      data: "aa"
    };
  }
  /* 
    1. props.data is coming from mapping component state to redux connect
    2. connect file and selectors are alright, because other parts of this component
       work as expected, and even same props.data is used elsewhere in the component
    3. a method wihtout input as in showAnotherComponent = () => false; will hide the 
       AnotherComponent element successfully. but even sth like 
       showAnotherComponent = (data) => false; will not work!!!
    4. props.data is properly injected to the render method, console.log(props.data)  in reder 
       method will display updated value.
    5. props.data is never null or undefined and so on ..
  */
  showAnotherComponent = data => data.flag === "AAA";

  render() {
    console.log(this.props.data); // will show the updated props.data

    return (
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-md-10">
          <h1>Some heading</h1>
        </div>
        <div className="col-md-2">
          {/* the element in next line will always show up invariably, whatever the
          content of props.data. tried ternary, same result. */}
          {this.showAnotherComponent({ flag: this.state.data }) && (
            <div>asdsdasd</div>
          )}
        </div>
        <button onClick={() => this.setState({ data: "AAA" })}>Toggle</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Click on Toggle and the Data will be displayed.

Comment: data prop is quite simple, and it always contains a string. in some cases its content could match the constant string in checker function. and only then i wanna render the second component in jsx conditional. thank you for the effort, but the issue is still there having checked all the mentioned things in comments and your post.